# get trouble in running roscore

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner. I entered "roscore" in the terminal, but I couln't get response when entering other command.
The response I got after I entered "roscore" as follow.

llq@ubuntu:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/llq/.ros/log/eb7e1dc8-e33a-11e0-bfba-f46d04bbb18e/roslaunch-ubuntu-4399.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:48966/
ros_comm version 1.6.2

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosversion
- /rosdistro

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4413]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/

setting /run_id to eb7e1dc8-e33a-11e0-bfba-f46d04bbb18e
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4426]
started core service [/rosout]

If I enter other commands like "rosnode list", it doesn't respond.
Where the problem is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11309/get-trouble-in-running-roscore/) by [llqazs](https://answers.ros.org/users/1121/llqazs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-09-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscore blocks your current terminal...
You have to use another terminal for your commands.

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2011-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [llqazs](https://answers.ros.org/users/1121/llqazs/) on 2011-09-26**:
Hi! Chrimo, thank you very much.  I'm new to the English website, so it took me several days to get used. Actually, I solved the problem a few days ago. But I didn't realise that I haven't submitted the question until this morning, just because I haven't logged in. I'm really please to join here.